# how can I make use of the word2vec pretrained vectors?

Tags: word2vec

I want to make use of the word2vec pretrained vectors to classify passages. Are there any well known good features I can extract from them? I've read that averaging the vectors across all of the words in the passage can be useful. here: https://github.com/Poyuli/sentiment.analysis

Is there any place I can find a good general discussion of getting the most out of the pretrained word2vec vectors that google provides?

Answer (score 0):

"averaging" is an efficient way for text classification.
I can suggest you to try **stanford GloVe** tool which does the same job of word2vec.
It has it's own pre-trained word vectors. You can check this site http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/